# Bootstrap 4 Combo Box

Tags: forms, jquery, bootstrap

I've been searching for a Bootstrap 4 input that allows one to select from a set of options or input a new value. Bootstrap-select is nearly what I want, but it doesn't allow someone to input a new value.

Comment: I clarified and shortened. Is this acceptable?

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with bootstrap so I cannot tell what might be missing. Just to be sure, please check with [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) It's in your own interest, to get good and matching answers. Good luck!